# automatic scrolling when using keytable plugin

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using Allan Jardine's [KeyTable](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/KeyTable) plugin in a plain html table. It's a big table so it scrolls horizontally and vertically. The problem I'm facing right now is that it doesn't scroll automatically when the focused cell is out of sight (one knows the current cell because it has the .focus class).

How do I make it scroll automatically when using the keyboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the nice scrollintoview plugin for jQuery: https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview for this.

My own code, which is nice but still not perfect, works like this:

```
var anim_element = $();
var keys = new KeyTable( {
  "table": t,
  focus: false,
});
keys.event.focus( null, null, function(cell, posx, posy) {
  /* handler for focus events on all cells ... */
  anim_element.stop();
  var row = $(cell).parents("tr").first();
  anim_element = row.stop().scrollintoview({ duration: 50, direction: 'y'});
});
```

Note that you have to stop the animation when the next focus event starts but to do so you have to have the previous animation element stored somewhere. This is the part of my code that's still a little rough.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like the options you gave here. In the end I chose a custom solution that I might post as an alternate answer. I'll give it a try and accept your answer if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using scrollX and scrollY in the DataTable Options

```
scrollX: true, // For Horizontal Scrolling
scrollY: "600px" // For Verticle Scrolling (define the pixels when scrolling should Start)
```

Reference :

https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX

https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY

It worked for me. I also checked it using KeyTable and it worked fine.